# Register application lifetime scoped service with Autofac in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

According to the [Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html), the `ContainerBuilder` in `ConfigureServices()` is already request-scoped:

> Use `InstancePerLifetimeScope` instead of `InstancePerRequest`. [...] With the introduction of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, the creation of per-request and other child lifetime scopes is now part of the conforming container provided by the framework, so all child lifetime scopes are treated equally - there’s no special “request level scope” anymore.

This makes the registration of request lifetime scoped services easier, but **how do I register a service as application lifetime scoped?**

### Context / Example

We have some services that provide information that doesn't change during the entire application lifetime, for example AutoMapper profiles. Some of them are compute intensive to instantiate, so I really want to instantiate them only at application startup time, and not for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SingleInstance` method that will create your component as a singleton.
If you want to instanciate them at application startup, you can let your component implement `IStartable` or register them with the `AutoActivate` method :

```
builder
   .RegisterType<TypeRequiringWarmStart>()
   .SingleInstance()
   .AutoActivate();
```

See [Instance scope - single instance](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance) and [Running code at startup](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html) for more information

Comment: Wouldn't `SingleInstance` create a single instance within the lifetime scope we register on? If that's the case, then we're back to instance per request...

Comment: @theDmi : nop, Single Instance means that the component will be created once for the container. See [instance scope - single instance](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Cyril's answer, you could register the service using the built-in container. When you call Autofac's `Populate` method, it will register the service with application scope.

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```